# How to display LocalFolder images in a flipview (Universal Windows Development)

Tags: image, uwp-xaml, getfiles, flipview

A portion of xaml below. App Throws/Raises no any error. also App generates exact slides count. but just getting gray empty areas. it slides; but areas are empty.

```
 <FlipView x:Name="flipView1"">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image>
                     <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding PicFiles}" />
                </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

and codebehind

```
public sealed partial class PresentationPage : Page
{

    public ObservableCollection<Uri> PicFiles;
    public PresentationPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        PicFiles = new ObservableCollection<Uri>();
        GetPicFilesFromStorePath();
    }

    private void GetPicFilesFromStorePath()
    {
        var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

        var a = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpg"));

        foreach (var x in a)
        {
            PicFiles.Add(new Uri(x,UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        flipView1.ItemsSource = PicFiles;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the above code get the full file-system path property of the file for accessing, which is not recommended. You could use [`StoragFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) relative APIs. Details please reference [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile). [`QueryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.queryoptions) can be used for filtering in your situation.

Secondly, give full file-system path value to  the [`UriSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_BitmapImage_UriSource) property will not work. To access files stored in the app data, you should use `Uri` with the `ms-appdata:` scheme. Details you can reference [How to load file resources (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Lastly, the binding is not in the correct way, you're binding the whole collection to the `UriSource` property, actually it requires one `Uri` value of the collection.

So the updated complete code snippet as follows:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" >
   <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Image  >
               <Image.Source>
                   <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding}" />
               </Image.Source>
           </Image>
       </DataTemplate>
   </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void GetPicFilesFromStorePath()
{
    //var path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

    //var a = Directory.GetFiles(Name, "*.*").Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpg"));

    //foreach (var x in a)
    //{
    //    PicFiles.Add(new Uri((String.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}", x))));
    //}

    StorageFolder localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
    StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = localfolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
    var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile x in files)
    {
        PicFiles.Add(new Uri((String.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}", x.Name))));
    }
    flipView1.ItemsSource = PicFiles;
}
```

Comment: problem already solved via  using "ms-appdata:///local/" prefix after losing 8 hours. I return here to answer my question now. and saw answered the correct answer after a day.

Answer (score 0):

similar solution. Somewhere I read {x:binding} is faster than {Binding}

```
namespace Project1.Models
{
    public class PicFile
    {
        public Uri Img { get; set; }
    }

    public static class PicFileManager
    {
        private static readonly ObservableCollection<PicFile> PicFiles = new ObservableCollection<PicFile>();
        public static ObservableCollection<PicFile> GetPicFilesFromStorePath()
        {

            string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Portaokul");

            var a = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpg"));

            PicFiles.Clear();
            foreach (var x in a)
            {
                Uri uri_ = new Uri(
                   Path.Combine("ms-appdata:///local/Project1", Path.GetFileName(x)));

                PicFiles.Add(new PicFile { Img= uri_ });
            }
            return PicFiles; 
        }
    }
}
```

in Page

```
 public PresentationPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        flipView1.ItemsSource = PicFileManager.GetPicFilesFromStorePath();
```

}

in xaml

```
 <FlipView x:Name="flipView1">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PicFile">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind Img}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

and on top of xaml

```
   xmlns:models="using:Project1.Models"
```